# How to solve Formula Error is solved in Macro

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to run this formula in module but unable to figure out what is missing.
The Formula is `=IF('301'!$F$10=0,"-",'301'!$F$10)`. Its concept is it will take the values to all those sheets started with number with their relevant `Range("F10")` and pasted in to `"Strength"` Sheet started from `Range("D4")` to the last row

```
Sub Strength()
    Dim i As Long
    Dim LastRow As Long

    LastRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For i = 4 To LastRow
    '=IF('301'!$F$10=0,"-",'301'!$F$10)
        Range("D" & i).Formula = "=IF('" & Worksheets(i - 1).Name & "'!$F$10=0, ""-"" & , ' & Worksheets(i - 1).Name & '!$F$10)"
    Next i
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

I grateful if the problem is solved.

Thanks & Regards

Muneeb

Comment: In the title you state the issue is solved. Is that want you want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Range("D" & i).Formula = "=IF("& Worksheets(i- 1).Name &"!$F$10=0,""-"","& Worksheets(i- 1).Name &"!$F$10)"
```

or if you must the single quote (gap in worksheet name) then use

```
Range("D" & i).Formula = "=IF('"& Worksheets(i- 1).Name &"'!$F$10=0,""-"",'"& Worksheets(i- 1).Name &"'!$F$10)"
```

Comment: Thanks xShen I am grateful for your support and precious time. It's perfectly working.

Answer (score 1):

Using a formula template improves code clarity, avoiding errors with quotes, and outputting an array to a worksheet in a single operation increases speed. It is also advisable to specify precisely the books, worksheets, and ranges to be processed

```
Option Explicit

Sub Strength()
    Dim i As Long, LastRow As Long, arr
    Const FORMULA_T = "=IF('#'!$F$10=0,""-"",'#'!$F$10)"  'a template; # will be replaced by WS names
    
    With ActiveSheet
        LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
        ReDim arr(4 To LastRow, 1 To 1) 'make the array to store the formulae before output to the WS
        For i = 4 To LastRow
            arr(i, 1) = Replace(FORMULA_T, "#", .Parent.Worksheets(i - 1).Name)   ' fill the arr with formulae
        Next i
        .Range("D4").Resize(UBound(arr) - LBound(arr) + 1).Formula = arr 'output the array to the WS at once
    End With
End Sub
```